Azure Static Web App toggle to use staticwebapp.config.json not working
I want Azure Static Web App to use my own staticwebapp.config.json file.
I navigate to:
Static Web App->Settings/Configuration->General settings tab->Configuration file
And trying to set 'checked' to "Enable configuration file changes" checkbox.
I set 'checked', press Save button, reload page but checkbox is not checked.
So I cannot save field "Enable configuration file changes".
Any browser the same issue.
What could be the issue?

What is the framework of your app?Can you please share the git hub repo.

@Harshitha I found an issue. If you press refresh button on dashboard -> everything appears correctly. But if you press refresh button on Chrome -> the checkbox will disappear. I contact Microsoft support and the approved such glitch.

I found an issue. If you press refresh button on dashboard -> everything appears correctly. But if you press refresh button on Chrome -> the checkbox will disappear. I contact Microsoft support and the approved such glitch.

